# Count how many records of unique values there are in the data set

Tags: r

I have a data set where there are 7 unique marker codes. I want to know if there is a way to count the number of records for each of the 7 unique marker codes.

```
unique(Assign1North$marker_codes)
[1] "COI-5P|COI-5P"                             "COI-5P"                                   
[3] NA                                          "COI-5P|COI-5P|COI-5P|COI-5P|COI-5P|COI-5P"
[5] "COI-5P|COI-5P|COI-5P|COI-5P"               "COI-5P|COI-5P|COI-5P"                     
[7] "COI-5P|COI-5P|COI-5P|COI-5P|COI-5P"
```

Comment: do you need `table(Assign1North$marker_codes)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I just tried that and it worked, thank you.